# Filtering a listview c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm using this example and it work good when I use only on a string member, However , I would like to use it on a class model :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.ListView_control.FilteringSample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="FilteringSample" Height="200" Width="300">
<DockPanel Margin="10">
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,10" Name="txtFilter" TextChanged="txtFilter_TextChanged" />
    <ListView Name="lvUsers">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</DockPanel>
```

```
public partial class FilteringSample : Window
{
    public FilteringSample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<User> items = new List<User>();
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42 });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39 });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 13 });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Donna Doe", Age = 13 });
        lvUsers.ItemsSource = items;

        CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvUsers.ItemsSource);
        view.Filter = UserFilter;
    }

    private bool UserFilter(object item)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFilter.Text))
            return true;
        else
            return ((item as User).Name.IndexOf(txtFilter.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
    }

    private void txtFilter_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvUsers.ItemsSource).Refresh();
    }
}

public enum SexType { Male, Female };

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Mail { get; set; }

    public SexType Sex { get; set; }
}
```

}

**Link of the tuto :**

[ListView filtering](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-filtering/)

[image]

As you can see on the image shown , I would like to search for the Name and the Age , not only the name , how can I filter the two fields not at the same time?

Comment: You should use the `ObjectListView`. It has build-in filter in multi-columns functionality.
See [ObjectListView documentation](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your LvUsers ItemSource property to the CollectionView, not to the List of Users. Also you have to define the Filter method of the CollectionView in the `txtFilter_TextChanged` method, this way whenever you change the text the filtering occurs. Like this:

```
public partial class FilteringSample: Window {
      ListCollectionView Users {
        get;
        set;
      }
      public FilteringSample() {
        InitializeComponent();
        List < User > users = new List < User > {
          new User() {
            Name = "John Doe", Age = 42
          },
          new User() {
            Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39
          },
          new User() {
            Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 13
          },
          new User() {
            Name = "Donna Doe", Age = 13
          },
        };
        Users = (ListCollectionView) CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(users);
        lvUsers.ItemsSource = Users;
      }

      private void txtFilter_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
        Users.Filter = item => {
          User user = item as User;
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFilter.Text))
            return true;
          else {
            string concat = $ "{user.Name} {user.Age}";
            return concat.ToLower().Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToLower());
          }
        };
      }
    }
```

As you can see in the `txtFilter_TextChanged` I concat the the Name and the Age fields, this way you can search by whatever field you like of the `User` object.